# Python NLP: Get synonyms for a word based on my own corpus

Tags: python, nlp, synonym

I have a large corpus of text (about 3 GB of plain text).

I want to build a search function.

When the user enters a keyword, I want to display a list of other keywords that are closely related.

For this, I don't want to use any generic synonym dictionary. Instead, I want a function to...

1. see which other words keyword 1 usually "goes with" in my corpus
2. find what other words these same words are also commonly associated with, other than my keyword 1 (which would be keyword 2, keyword 3, etc.)

Any ideas for approaches, libraries or examples here? I'm also open for suggestions for a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Train a word2vec or FastText model on your corpus.
2. For each keyword, find its nearest neighbors in the space of embeddings learned by the model above.

You can use for example [Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) library to do it in Python.